# Possible to show two variables legend in same grid by ggplot (geom_line)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, line-plot

At first, sorry for the inaccurate description because I'm not a native speaker :(

I tried really hard to use ggplot as a tool to draw images like this (also written by R in plot {graphics} function):
[image: Images wanted]
Cuz i want to practice ggplot so i try to draw the same one, and it turns out this is what i can do the best.... I cannot combine these exp variabla (exp1, exp2) into the same grid, if deleting the `facet_grid(. ~ Exp)`, error orrurs: `geom_path: If you are using dotted or dashed lines, colour, size and linetype must be constant over the line`.

[image: Images i can do the best]

here is my code:

```
allDraw %>% ggplot(aes(x=PrimeType, y=mRT, shape=SOA,linetype=SOA,group=SOA,color=Exp))+
  geom_line(size=0.5,alpha=0.6) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c('black', 'blue'))+
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid", "twodash"))+
  labs(y='RT', title= 'RT on Prime Types & SOA')+
  ylim(c(600,900))+
  geom_point(size = 2)+ 
  facet_grid(. ~ Exp)+ #if delete this line the image fails to show
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mRT - SE, ymax = mRT + SE), width = .1, size=0.6, alpha=0.6)

#dataset (not sure if this way of pasting data is right...)

> dput(allDraw)
structure(list(PrimeType = c("Control", "Control", "Homophone", 
"Homophone", "Semantic", "Semantic", "Control", "Control", "Homophone", 
"Homophone", "Semantic", "Semantic"), SOA = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("85", "150"
), class = "factor"), mRT = c(775.085416666667, 762.44, 779.744166666667, 
753.494166666667, 741.287083333333, 725.580833333333, 792.747916666667, 
798.07125, 706.307916666667, 700.527916666667, 800.543333333333, 
771.0625), N = c(24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L), SE = c(20.1588447968423, 23.9092193121386, 20.4126104540678, 
22.2091770912669, 15.9753977914136, 22.6038502469004, 27.3474259511178, 
28.550485720839, 19.48170159647, 24.2353984949669, 35.3326209440763, 
25.6053095168346), Exp = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

here is my dataset ("allDraw" in the code)

| PrimeType | SOA | mRT | N | SE | Exp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Control | 85 | 775.0854166666670 | 24 | 20.158844796842300 | 1 |
| Control | 150 | 762.4400000000000 | 24 | 23.909219312138600 | 1 |
| Homophone | 85 | 779.7441666666670 | 24 | 20.412610454067800 | 1 |
| Homophone | 150 | 753.4941666666670 | 24 | 22.209177091266900 | 1 |
| Semantic | 85 | 741.2870833333330 | 24 | 15.975397791413600 | 1 |
| Semantic | 150 | 725.5808333333330 | 24 | 22.603850246900400 | 1 |
| Control | 85 | 792.7479166666670 | 24 | 27.347425951117800 | 2 |
| Control | 150 | 798.07125 | 24 | 28.55048572083900 | 2 |
| Homophone | 85 | 706.3079166666670 | 24 | 19.48170159647000 | 2 |
| Homophone | 150 | 700.5279166666670 | 24 | 24.23539849496690 | 2 |
| Semantic | 85 | 800.5433333333330 | 24 | 35.33262094407630 | 2 |
| Semantic | 150 | 771.0625 | 24 | 25.605309516834600 | 2 |

Hope somebody knows some methods to draw a plot like the first image by `ggplot`.

Comment: Hi OP - for sharing you dataset, can you do the following instead:  type `dput(allDraw)` in the console, then copy and paste the resulting code into your question instead of what you have pasted.  The output of `dput()` should start with `structure(...`.

Comment: I don't know why the table fails to show the correct format (seems right in preview mode....)
Can anyone help QQ?

Comment: That's the point though - the table is formatted correct now with some editing help, but it's much easier to help if you can supply your data as code.  All someone has to do to replicate your dataset with the `dput()` method is to copy and paste that code into their own console, so it's a great way to share the values and data types of everything.

Comment: @chemdork123 Thanks! I will try.... sorry for inconvenience (I am new to this place QQ)

Comment: @chemdork123 Am I doing this right? I've pasted some results but not sure I am doing okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change the group to something like this `paste(SOA, Exp)`

```
allDraw %>% ggplot(aes(x=PrimeType, y=mRT, shape=SOA,linetype=SOA,group=paste(SOA, Exp),color=Exp))+
  geom_line(size=0.5,alpha=0.6) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c('black', 'blue'))+
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid", "twodash"))+
  labs(y='RT', title= 'RT on Prime Types & SOA')+
  ylim(c(600,900))+
  geom_point(size = 2)+ 
  #facet_grid(. ~ Exp)+ #if delete this line the image fails to show
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mRT - SE, ymax = mRT + SE), width = .1, size=0.6, alpha=0.6)
```

Comment: wow... it really works! I dont know the `paste` syntax, Thanks a lot!